# Htaccess rewrite variables into pretty folder structure

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website and htaccess located in folder /new/ from webroot.

I have the following htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^visit-([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2  [L]
RewriteRule ^visit-([a-z\-]+)$ index.php?var1=$1   [L]
```

For a url like

```
domain.com/new/visit-spain
```

it is working correct - i.e. it loads index.php and passes the $1 to var1 variable

For a url like

```
domain.com/new/visit-spain/text-file
```

It does not work correctly. Index.php isnt loaded.

Help is greately appreciated. I have spent all day trying to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a go:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^visit-(?:([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|)$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
```

Basically this will take care of both of your case it would be the same of(and either will work for your case):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^visit-([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^visit-([^/]+)/?$ index.php?var1=$1 [L]
```

Where `([^/]+)` will get anything after `visit-` that is not a `/` and for the 2nd case the same however it will do it for the first and 2nd parameters.

Also you might want to add after `RewriteEngine On` the following:

```
RewriteBase /new/
```